# Catboost at Vertex AI endpoint prediction error : ValueError: Unable to coerce value

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, catboost

I built and deployed a CatBoost regressor model on Vertex AI and I am trying to make some predictions using Vertex AI python SDK. Here's my code:

```
sample = [[2.0200e+03, 4.5000e+01, -2.6090e+01, -2.4440e+01, 3.8000e+01, 2.0201e+05]]

# get prediction
response = endpoint.predict(sample)
y_pred = response.predictions[0][0]

print('API response: ', response)
print('Predicted Value: ', y_pred)
```

And the error:

```
ValueError: Unable to coerce value: array([ 2.0200e+03,  4.5000e+01, -2.6090e+01, -2.4440e+01,  3.8000e+01,  2.0201e+05])
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Vertex AI endpoints do not accept ndarray and array types as input. Rather, you need to convert it into a python list.

Whether your `sample` list is an [numpy `ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) or a [python built-in `array object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.fromlist), you can convert it to a list like this:

```py
sample.tolist()
```

I am not sure about the type of the `sample` object in your code above because the syntax you posted would create a list within a list, not a numpy array, which doesn't have `tolist()`:

```py
>>> sample.tolist()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

This is not explicitly mentioned anywhere nor is the Vertex AI error informative. More on data types for prediction can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/get-predictions#deploy_a_model_to_an_endpoint